# Стили для модулей в Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular2, webpack

Есть приложение на Angular 2. В нем есть 2 модуля (один для самого сайта, другой для админки), не считая главного модуля App. Возник следующий вопрос, как для каждого модуля подключать свои стили? По дефолту все стили собираются в один файл, но нет смысла для юзера который зашел на сайт - грузить стили админки. 
Приложение собирается через Webpack

Comment: Сделать два два разных app.module и два разных entry point'а?

Comment: Как можно сделать два разных app.module в рамках одного приложения?